# echo <script> itself in php

Tags: php, echo

hello every body i had a problem with echo in php that might be very simple but i'm a bit new in php.
i had a code like this:

```
<?php echo '<script>var str=Array(1);str.push('.$user_id.')</script>';?>
```

in this code i want to display script text instead of calling java script. what shall i do?

i have already tried every kind of writing types such as single quotes and double quotes like below

```
<?php echo '"<script>"var str=Array(1);str.push('.$user_id.')"</script>"';?>
```

even tried \ at the beginning and end of script but none of them worked.

Comment: Is your browser dev console reporting any javascript errors when the page loads?

Comment: `<?php echo '<script>var str=Array(1);str.push("'.$user_id.'")</script>';?> `

Comment: Or `<?php echo "<script>var str=Array(1);str.push('$user_id')</script>";?>`

Comment: Or `<?php echo '<script>var str = '. json_encode(array($user_id)) .';</script>';?>`

Comment: no it just calls java script in inspect element.

Comment: What does "*it just calls java script in inspect element*" mean? I think you may be confusing terms, which is in turn confusing us what your question is. Could you add an example of the exact expected result you are aiming for?

Comment: thank you guys but none of them worked. and incredible hat $user_id is not an array and i dont want to call java script i just want to echo <script>'s text itself.

Comment: this is the result i want to get from the echo:<script>var str=Array(1);str.push("100")</script>

Comment: Your javascript is treating it as an array `Array(1)` and `.push`. Therefore, it IS an array. Also `<script>` has no text. Its a single variable assignment.

Comment: i have a pop up box that when user clickes on a link it is popped and tells the user to put this code starting with <script> in his html file.

Comment: <?php echo htmlspecialchars('<script>var str=Array(1);str.push('.$user_id.')</script>');?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `htmlspecialchars()` function to escape html tags.

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars('<script>var str=Array(1);str.push('.$user_id.')</script>');?>
```